# Multithreading WCF with ADO.NET and SQL Server connection throws "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, wcf, ado.net

I have a WCF service that is connecting to a SQL Server database.

WCF code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyWebService : IMyWebService
{
    public IList<IDictionary<string, object>> Select()
    {
        return nee MyRepository().Select("SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE_T");
    }
}
```

Repository code:

```
public IList<IDictionary<string, object>> Select(string sqlQuery, params SqlParameter[] pars)
{
    IList<IDictionary<string, object>> list = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, Connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(pars);

        if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            command.Connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> keyPair = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    keyPair.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));

                list.Add(keyPair);
            }
        }

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        _connection.Dispose();
           _connection = null;
    }

    return list;
}
```

This works fine when just one machine is calling, but when put two or more machines I get an error

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

and the connection to SQL Server fails until restart.

PS: my real web service code executes more operations like inserts and updates. For each operation I create a new connection to the database server, always surrounding the command with `using`.

**Update 1**: (requested in the comments)

My connection code:

```
private SqlConnection _connection = null;

protected SqlConnection Connection
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_connectionString))
                throw new NotImplementedException("Missing _connectionString");

            if (_connection == null)
                _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                _connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

            _connection.Open();

            return _connection;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _lastConnectErrorMessage = e.Message;
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not sharing any object between threads/requests, are you? Both the repository as well as _connection are strictly private to their request?

Comment: you don't need to check the `ConnectionState`. Always open it and close it when the only data access is happening inside your one method.

Comment: also, you should not open the connection in your `get;` accessor. open it in each method you are using.

Comment: Perhaps checking whether your **reader.HasRows** might solve a few problems. Otherwise, I fear a concurrency issue, while a client connects, it enters the same loop and once one is out, everything gets closed, but then, you have another client trying to read the information, and bang! The exception occurs... Try some locking or perform some multithreading processes.

Comment: Dictionary serializable ?

Comment: Similar like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514844/executing-a-custom-sql-query-over-wcf

Answer (score 3):

A couple things.

- Use either `command.Connection` or `_connection` while referencing the connection - it does not look like they are the same instance.
- wrap a `using` statement around the Connection object as well to be consistent, instead of explicitly calling `Dispose()`
- Don't check the `ConnectionState` when you are calling `_connection.Open()`. Always open it and always close it. The data provider will handle connection pooling if necessary.
- Close your `DataReader` by calling `reader.Read()` after you are done with the `DataReader`
- You aren't closing your connection after your `DataReader` use. Always close it explicitly by either passing `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` in your `ExecuteReader()` method or calling `_connection.Close()` after all your data access.

Comment: To add to this answer, the `SqlConnection` object implents the `IDisposable` interface--enclose it in a `using` statement.

Comment: But how do these defects explain the error message?

Comment: Yes. I can see that `_connection` is being Disposed, by explicitly calling `Dispose()`, but wrapping it in a `using` statement will keep it consistent.

Comment: @usr - the connection is being disposed of before it's being explicitly closed, so it could be in a different state than `Open`.

Comment: @CamBruce where does he dispose the connection he uses? He doesn't do that at all. He disposes a different connection. (I now assume the code is not what he executes and voted to close.)

Comment: @usr my first point tells him to make sure he's using the right connection reference throughout his method.

Comment: I'm testing with CommandBehavior.CloseConnection with 15 threads making requests. If this works I'll make the tests with 75 threads and see if the exception happens again.